# Cannot capture special keys in C/C++ keylogger using GetAsyncKeyState

Tags: c++, keylogger

I wrote a small key logger in C/C++ with the intent to capture all keys pressed. However, I am not able to capture some special keys such as *; : [ ] \ / ? " ' .*

Let's consider I want to capture the *;* or *:* key. 
Currently, I have the following code snippet in an infinite loop:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(0xBA) == -32767)
    {
        //the statements inside the if clause are not executed when the key is pressed
        std::ofstream write("Record.txt", ios::app);
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(0x10))
            write << ":";
        else
            write << ";";

    }
```

where 0x10 is the code of the "SHIFT" virtual key (VK_SHIFT) and VK_OEM_1 (0xBA) is the virtual key for *;*, as decribed in the Microsoft Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes.

As far as I acknowledge, the `GetAsyncKeyState` function returns -32767 after a key was just released.

The code above works for other virtual keys or simple keys, as described in the ASCII table (e.g. `GetAsyncKeyState(48)` works for the *0* key, `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RETURN)` works for the *ENTER* key and so on.

I've already tried inputting the following arguments for the `GetAsyncKeyState` function:

1. The ASCII code for '*;*' , which is 59
2. The ';' character
3. VK_OEM_1 - the virtual key
4. 0xBA - the virtual's key value in hex
5. 186, as I've found here: https://www.amibroker.com/guide/afl/getasynckeystate.html.

None of the arguments makes the function return -32767 when the '*;*' key is pressed.

Do you have any idea of how am I supposed to use that function in order to capture that key and, consequently, all the other keys that are not captured by my approach ( *[ ] \ / ? " ' .*)?

P.S: I am using the standard English (US) keyboard layout.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It returns 2 bits of info, bit #0 and bit #15.  Simplest way to test if a key is down is with GetAsyncKeyState(key) < 0, tells you that bit #15 is turned on, regardless of the bit #0 state.

Comment: Tried previously, without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Seems like Visual Studio is going crazy when you hide the console from the screen (it's like you change something in the code, but when you run again the application, the changes are not propagated).

However, I want to share with you some possible mistakes that may lead to the error that I've encountered:

1. If you use a `char` variable to store the ASCII code, for some keys it may exceed the maximum `char` size, thus I suggest using an `unsigned char` or an `int`.
2. If you plan to iterate through the list of all possible ASCII codes, try going up to the size of the Extended ASCII table. Do not limit to the standard one.

Here's the corresponding snippet of code regarding the issue that may help you:

```
int main()
{
    while (1){
    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 255; i++){
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767) {
                if (i == VK_OEM_1) {
                    cout << ";";
                }
            }

        // ....
    }
}
```

}